# MongoDB update many documents Schema.Types.Mixed

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hi i need some help with MongoDB and Schema.Types.Mixed.
I have this model:

```js
let userSchema = Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: { type: String },
  categories: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: []}
})
```

This is how the users are stored in DB, the schema types mixed is an array of objects.

```js
let user = {
    categories: [
        {name: 'fruit'},
        {name: 'spices'},
        {name: 'cofee'},
    ]
};
```

How can i update this objects? i need to create a new property called sortedProducts with an empty array as default:

```js
let user = {
    categories: [
        {name: 'fruit', sortedProducts: []},
        {name: 'spices', sortedProducts: []},
        {name: 'cofee', sortedProducts: []},
    ]
};
```

I tryed this, but i realiced that i need to iterate categories array to set correctly. How can i do this in mongoDB console? Thanks in advance

```js
db.users.updateMany({}, {$set: {"categories.sortedProducts": []}})
```

Comment: use positional `$[]` operator to add in all objects of array `{"categories.$[].sortedProducts": []}`